# Configuring AWS cluster using automation script

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, automation, hortonworks-data-platform

We are looking for the possibility of an automation script which we can give how many master and data nodes we need and it would configure a cluster. Probably giving the credentials in a properties file.

Currently our approach is to login to the console and configure the Hadoop cluster. It would be great if there could be an automated way around it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done very nicely using [Foreman](http://theforeman.org), [Chef](https://www.chef.io), and [Ambari Blueprints](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Blueprints). Foreman was used to provision the VMs, Chef scripts were used to install Ambari, configure the Ambari blueprint, and to create the cluster using the Blueprint.